# How to move my avocado seedling from state to state?

Tags: avocado

I am moving across several states and I have an avocado seedling that I have not planted in soil yet. I am wondering if I take the seedling (which is quite large) and wrap it in damp paper towels, if it will make the trip. I think it will be about 3 to 4 days.

Answer (score 1):

Sure I think it is very possible. Key will be to wrap carefully and immobilize it in a rigid box of some kind (in particular avoid damage to the root), then during transport keep the box out of direct sunlight and heat; ideal temperature would be about 60F. See if you can catch the large leaves when they are parallel to the stem as they may be from time to time as the plant dries down a bit to reduce possibility of mechanical damage breaking leaf stems as the wrapping progresses.